# Qt::ToolTipRole not getting triggered

Tags: qt, tooltip, model-view

I am using a model implemented using QAbstractTableModel. I want to show individual tooltips for all the headers. In the data() and headerData() implementations, however, When I print the role, it is never becoming Qt::ToolTipRole. Is there anything else I have to do to trigger the tooltiprole here?

```
QVariant jlsGenericReportTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    printf("Role in data() = %d\n",role);
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {

        //        printf(" --- Returned\n");
        if(_dataStore)
        {
            if(index.row() < _dataStore->RowCount())
            {
                return _dataStore->DataForTuple(index.row(),index.column());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(index.row() < _rows.size())
            {
                return _rows.at(index.row())->DataForColumn(index.column());
            }
        }
    }
else if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole )
{

    if (( (QMetaType::Type)(data(index,Qt::DisplayRole)).type()) == QMetaType::QString)
        return QVariant(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    else
        return QVariant(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter);
}
else if (role == Qt::ToolTipRole) {
    printf("Triggered\n");     //Doesn't come here
    //if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
        return QString("Horizontal Header No. ");
    //else
      //  return QString("Vertical Header No. ");
}
return QVariant();
```

}

Comment: What view are you using with the model?

Comment: Hi Frank, I am using QTableView here.

Comment: For the headers, you should reimplement headerData()

Comment: I am reimplementing it too. But the role isn't coming out to be Qt::ToolTipRole ever.

Comment: In data() it is working though